# In Dyalog APL, how do I turn off auto-scaling in a Form?

Tags: winforms, scale, default-value, apl, dyalog

In the examples in the Dyalog chm help file on drawing simple lines in a form, I drilled down into all of the various options you can place on a Form window creation and could not find a way to turn off the auto-scaling.   That is, when I resize the Form, I don't want any object drawn within it to rescale their respective sizes in relation to the the new window size.

```
'F' ⎕WC 'Form' 'Drawing Lines' ('Size' 25 50) ('Coord' 'Pixel')
'F.Line' ⎕WC 'Poly' ((10 90)(5 60))
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

My initial comment was mistaken - the [Attach](http://help.dyalog.com/17.0/Content/GUI/Properties/Attach.htm)-property deals with form-fields. Your form should use `'AutoConf''0` to avoid propagation of size-changes to child-objects.

`'F' ⎕WC 'Form' 'Drawing Lines' ('Size' 25 50) ('Coord' 'Pixel')('AutoConf'0) ⋄ 'F.Line' ⎕WC 'Poly' ((10 90)(5 60))`